# Why the energy and momentum conservation equations do not include terms reflecting the particle nature of the photons?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, photons, momentum, wave-particle-duality

It is well known that light has a dual nature. However, the energy and momentum conservation equations embody the wave aspect of light but not the material aspect of the photon. Should there be additional terms reflecting this aspect of the photon as in the photoelectric and Compton effect?

Comment: What do you consider to be “the energy and momentum conservation equations”?

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking at the Maxwellian versions of these equations before we knew light had momentum? Certainly this is accounted for in QM, it is the original impetus for it!

Comment: @maury Classical electromagnet waves carry momentum; a thing well known in the late 19th century.

Answer (score 2):

Classical electromagentic waves and photons are two ways of modeling the same phenomena. The momentum carried by a beam of light is not "wave momentum" *plus* "particle momentum", it's just the one momentum that can be described either way.

For certain observable phenomena it is clearer to chose one description than the other, but this is a choice of how to describe the thing not a selection of a subset.